# ngrx/effects 5.2.0 reporting ts2684

Tags: angular, rxjs

Why it has been reporting ts2684:the'this'context of type'void' is not assignable to method's'this'?

```
 @Effect()
  loadList$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.ofType('LOAD').pipe(
    map(()=>{
      console.log(1);
      return new LoadSuccess();
    })
 );
```

Comment: `pipe(
    map(` critical surgery

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason:)
map should be import from 'rxjs/operators' rather than 'rxjs/operators/map'